# Auto insert the logged user in a Foreign Key

Tags: python, django

I'm creating an API for something like 9gag project that I'm doing, and upon uploading a post the logged user to be auto inserted in the created_by field that I have in my Post model

I've tried ton of things, from the Django doc's -- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user , tried overriding the save_model method in the admin.py but nothing seems to work.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TAGS)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False, blank=True, editable=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=False)
```

views.py

```
class PostCreated(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['id']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.created_by = self.request.user.pk
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

and when I upload something i always get

```
    "created_by": null
```

Comment: oh and I forgot to mention I am using 'from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser' , also I think I went over all of the stackoverflow answers for this topic and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set it on the instance, not the form. And you should use the actual object rather than the pk.

```
form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
```

(Although I don't understand why your fields list contains just the id. How are the rest of the fields getting populated? And id isn't even editable anyway.)

**Edit**

As is clear in the comments, the view you have posted here is not the view that is actually creating the Post. In fact this view does not appear to have anything to do with anything, and it is not clear why you have defined it. You should delete it.

Your Post creation is happening in the PostViewSet, so that is where you should be setting the user. For information about customising viewsets you should be looking at the rest-framework docs; as [explained there](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods), the method you need to override is `perform_create`. So:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
```

Comment: originally it was like that but it didn't work so I tried to change it to see if it would be any different. Just changed it back I still get created_by = null.

Comment: I don't think this is actually the view you are using to create the post.

Comment: I am using 
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 queryset = Post.objects.all()
 serializer_class = PostSerialize
could this be the problem?

Comment: So what is this PostCreated view for? Why do you have it? What is supposed to be calling it? Why don't you set the user in the PostViewSet?

Comment: I'm passing it to the urls.py like this -- router.register(r'upload', PostViewSet), I've tried overriding the form_valid method but its seems like it is now available in it.

Comment: That didn't answer any of my questions. But see my edit for the actual solution.

Comment: I'm getting this now -- Got a `TypeError` when calling `Post.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Post.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the PostSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `created_by`, fixed.

Comment: That was the problem, yep. And again, thank you for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not set this at the `form` level, but the `instance` wrapped in the `form`:

```
class PostCreated(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['id']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

> **Note**: You probably want to include all fields *except* `id` and `created_by` here?

Comment: it was form.instance.created_by = self.request.user originally but tried to fiddle with it to see if it would be any different but without luck, I also just removed the fields just now, if I remember correctly if there is no field it Django will include all the fields by default? And still i get created_by = null

Comment: @Uponn: then you likely do use another view, since this one will only provide *one* field: the `id`.

Comment: You are correct, I am using -- class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 queryset = Post.objects.all()
 serializer_class = PostSerializer but here I don't have the form_valid method

Comment: @Uponn: a `ModelViewSet` is usually used for (REST) APIs, not for web rendering.

Comment: I'm creating a rest api, yea, so the process is different for achieving the desired result?